# Node.js: Problem in find() using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have a document such as:

```
{ _id: 4e69bbedee97560001000011,
  case_id: '5', ... }
```

If I do:

```
Case.find {_id : "4e69bbedee97560001000011"}, (err,docs) ->
    docs.forEach (item, i) ->
        console.log item
```

It works fine but if I do:

```
Case.find {case_id : "5"}, (err,docs) ->
    docs.forEach (item, i) ->
        console.log item
```

It doesn't. `case_id` is a string. Why is this not working? Thanks

It works when I use the mongo console:

> db.case_notebooks.find({"case_id" :  5})

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e69bbedee97560001000011"), "case_id" : 5, "notes" : [
```

Answer (score 3):

5 != "5" ;)

That´s the reason why it doesn´t match. Try the following:

```
Case.find {case_id : 5}, (err,docs) ->
    docs.forEach (item, i) ->
        console.log item
```

This is equivalent to your console sample ;)